# Bootstrap inline text box and search button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have search input box, that I want styled with the bootstrap with the bootstrap form-control look.  Problem is, I also want the search button on the same line as the search box.  I thought this could be done with form-inline, but when I add class form-control to the search box, the search button gets pushed to the next line:

```
<div class="input-group" >
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control" >
      <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" value="Search" id="addressSearch">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TLEbG/

If I remove class="form-control" from the input textbox, the button is displayed in-line:

http://jsfiddle.net/ETs9M/

How can I keep the form-contol box styling, while keeping the button inline?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using input groups: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/ this puts the button next to the textfield and makes it one component

Comment: Thanks.  Changed to the following and got it working:" `code` <div class="input-group" >
                          <input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control" >
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addressSearch"> Search
                          </span>
                    </div>

Comment: The link redirects to info about alerts, can you edit  it? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/

Answer (score 10):

This answer comes from the [original poster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796235/bootstrap-inline-text-box-and-search-button/22796612#comment34762677_22796612.):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/gVSi912QEI#

Comment: Pretty sure there is no such thing as `type="textbox"` ;)

Comment: Fixed :-) - sorry about that